# How/Whether to rewrite async:false AJAX function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I'm using an AJAX call with `async:false` to return data, like this:

```
var my_data = my_function(10, 20);

function my_function(value1, value2) {
    var returnData;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'my_function.php',
      data: { variable1: value1, variable2: value2 },
      success: function(data) { returnData = data; },
      async:false
    });
    return returnData;
};
```

Notice that I've set `async:false`, which is necessary in the context of my code, and works perfectly.

Howverer, at the JQuery API, this message is provided for the entry on async:

> As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is
>   deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options
>   instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as
>   jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success().

I'm having trouble making sense of that warning as regards my function, as I'm not using `$.Deferred` in my routine; the warning still may apply in a way I don't appreciate. So, is it safe to leave the code as-is, or should it be rewritten in light of the deprecation of `async`, and if so, how should it be rewritten? (I need the function performed synchronously.)

Many thanks!

Comment: Why is it required to use a sync request?

Comment: You can use the native Js Ajax request (using `XMLHttpRequest`) instead of jQuery's one if you wish to keep using a sync'ed request.

Comment: Not only is it deprecated in jQuery, it's also [deprecated in the specification](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning) (outside of webworkers).  Chrome at the very least is already displaying the warning, not sure about other browsers.  Expect it to stop working at some point - I wouldn't use it in any new code.

Comment: If you are using async: false as a way to ensure your ajax completes before performing some other action, you may be able to accomplish your goal using a promise.

Comment: I'm surprised no one provided a valid answer to this question. The question is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score -2):

The code you provided looks good. The following is a version that is being deprecated (don't do this):

```
var my_data = my_function(10, 20);

function my_function(value1, value2) {
    var returnData;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'my_function.php',
      data: { variable1: value1, variable2: value2 },
      async:false
    }).success(function(data) { returnData = data; });
   return returnData;
};
```